# Autokey won't start on Fedora 29

Tags: kde-plasma, autokey, fedora-29

I've been trying to get autokey to work on a fresh install of Fedora 29. Every attempt to start the application was met with an error and the process would die.

```
encountered an uncaught pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Fedora 29 uses python3 by default. When installing autokey-gtk and autokey-common, the following dependencies are pulled:

```
===================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                Arch                                          Version                                                 Repository                                      Size
===================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Removing:
 autokey-gtk                                            noarch                                        0.95.2-1.fc29                                           @fedora                                        376 k
Removing unused dependencies:
 autokey-common                                         noarch                                        0.95.2-1.fc29                                           @fedora                                        554 k
 gtksourceview2                                         x86_64                                        2.11.2-27.fc29                                          @fedora                                        3.4 M
 pygtksourceview                                        x86_64                                        2.10.1-18.fc29                                          @fedora                                        196 k
 python3-xlib                                           noarch                                        0.23-3.fc29                                             @fedora                                        881 k
 wmctrl                                                 x86_64                                        1.07-25.fc29                                            @fedora                                         67 k
```

The gtksourceview is for python2 and not for python3 which won't allow autokey to open a window when trying to start. You will need to install gtksourceview3 separately to provide the proper libraries for autokey-gtk in python3.

```
# sudo dnf install gtksourceview3 -y
```